# I need help to verify my answer. Analyze the running time for the function

Tags: algorithm

```
int func2(int n) { 
    int i, j;
    int sum;
    arr = new int[n];

    for (i = 0, j = 1; i < n; i++, j *= 2) {
        arr[i] = j;
    }
    
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= arr[i]; j++) {
            sum += (i + j);
        }
    }
    
    delete []arr;
    return sum; 
}
```

My thinking:
1st loop  runs n times. so running time is theta of N.  0(n) +
2nd loop
inner loop runs. j times which j= 1+ 2 + 4 + 8.   thats the sum of n(n+1) (2n+1)/6 ==> theta n^3

so Total Running time =  0(n)+ 0(n^3)

Please comment on my answer and let me know if my logic is correct or I am missing something. I am very new to programming.

Comment: if n >= 64 there will be overflow in the 1st loop, and I am not sure whether the result is UB or not (assuming C++, but may also depend on version)

Answer (score 5):

The first loop is O(n).

After running the first loop,

```
arr = [1, 2, 4, 8, ... , 2^(n-1)]
```

So, the second loop is

```
O(1+2+4+ ... +2^(n-1)) = O(2^n - 1) = O(2^n)
```

Total complexity is

```
O(n + 2^n) = O(2^n)
```

Comment: Thank you. i just got confused with the other sum 1+4+9+16  which is 1+2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2. . my question so for the last Nested loop you only considered the inner loop for 2^n  which is  O(2^n).  why  it is not O(n 2^n) ?

Answer (score 0):

The 1st loop is O(n), the 2nd is O(n) and the 3rd is 1+2+4+... = 2^n - 1.
Therefore, the total is O(n) + O(n 2^n) = O(n 2^n).